# C++ change border background color by code

Tags: c++, xaml

I am try to create change the color of border in windows apps, but it doest works.
this is my code in xaml:

```
<Border Name="color" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="219" Margin="530,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Background="#FF6A1A1A"/>
```

and the code in C++ :

```
this->color->Background->SetValue(RGB(255,255,255));
```

Comment: Are you changing the border (specified in XAML by `BorderBrush`), or the background?  Once you make up your mind, I think the solution will be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `SolidColorBrush` instance:

```
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
...

color->Background = ref new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a XAML element. For example:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
...
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlockBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF557EB9"/>
...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and reference:

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource BlockBackgroundBrush}" 
    Width="80" Height="80" />
```

And you code could be something like:

```
auto greenBrush = ref new SolidColorBrush(Colors::Green);
```

OR

```
auto myBrush = ref new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 90, 200, 90));
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.solidcolorbrush.ASPx

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, it cannot work, i try this before. Actually windows app is not support  CreateSolidBrush....

Comment: Hello. You may want to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.solidcolorbrush.ASPx